# Find gradient of function from laplace operator

Tags: integration, derivatives, vector-fields

If

\begin{equation}
\Delta u = (u_{x_1x_1}+4u_{x_2x_2}) 
\end{equation}
what would $\nabla u$ and $u$ become?

u is defined as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
u_{t}(x)-\Delta u(x) &=0, & & x \in \Omega, \quad t>0 \\
u(x, t) &=0, & & x \in \partial \Omega, \quad t>0 \\
u(x, 0) &=u_{0}(x), & & x \in \Omega
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

$\Omega$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: In your notation, is $\Delta u = u_{x_1 x_1} + u_{x_2 x_2}$?

Comment: It would be that the differential operator is scaled by a factor of $2$ in "length" in the $x_2$ direction.

Comment: No, it should be \begin{equation}
\Delta u = u_{x_1x_1}+4u_{x_2x_2} 
\end{equation}

Comment: But how is $\Delta u$ defined?

Comment: It is the laplace operator in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, basically $\Delta f=\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_1^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_2^{2}}$

Comment: So $$u_{x_1 x_1} + u_{x_2 x_2} = \Delta u = u_{x_1 x_1} + 4 u_{x_2 x_2}$$ implies $u_{x_2 x_2} = 0$, right?

Comment: What is the relationship between the first equation and the boundary value problem below?

Answer (score 1):

I think we would need to have either $$\nabla u = \begin{bmatrix}\frac\partial {\partial x_1}\\2\frac\partial {\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}u$$

or

$$\nabla u = \begin{bmatrix}\frac\partial {\partial x_1}\\\frac\partial {\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}u(x_1,2x_2)$$

Maybe because the coordinate system is stretched a factor of $2$ in $x_2$ direction or the partial differential operator itself is.

What will happen with the chain rule?